# Sqlalchemy composite unique constraint creates two individual indexes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am experimenting with Flask-User. Between Flask-User and Flask Flask-Sqlalchemy 2.4.4 is used and Sqlalchemy 1.3.20.

I have a model that will list actions that are available to logged in users based on the "role(s)" they have.  The engine I am using is MySQL (Mariadb).

```
class Actions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        primary_key=True
    )
    action = db.Column(
        db.String(64),
        nullable=False,
        unique=True
    )
    role_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey('roles.id')
    )

    db.UniqueConstraint(
        'action', 'role_id'
    )
```

The Sqlalchemy docs on `UniqueConstraint` ([here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint)) say that the `db.UniqueConstraint` above should create a composite unique key.  What I see in the database though are two, individual indexes: one (`action`) is unique but `role_id` is just a plain index.

I have also tried naming the constraint as in:

```
db.UniqueConstraint(
    'action', 'role_id', name='uix_action_role'
)
```

but that does not appear to create an index with that name.

Am I using `UniqueConstraint` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the composite `UniqueConstraint` as part of the `__table_args__`:

```py
class Actions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "actions"
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint("action", "role_id"),)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    action = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    role_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey("roles.id")
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.  that was not clear in the docs.